# using macros in defadvice

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have this code in my init:

```
(defadvice kill-buffer (around show-diff-rephrase-question activate compile)
  "Prompt when a buffer is about to be killed."
  (case (read-char-choice
         "(s/k/q)? "
         (append "sSKkQq" nil))
    ((?s ?S)
     ad-do-it)
    ((?k ?K)
     ad-do-it)
    ((?q ?Q) nil))
  ad-do-it)
```

It works when I call `eval-buffer` to evaluate it.  However, if I compile the init file, I get

> Invalid function: (115 83)

If I insert the macro expansion of the `(case ...)` sexp, then it works as a compiled file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))` somewhere before this definition: `case` is not a predefined macro.  Adding `(require 'cl)` would work as well, but would cause `cl` to be loaded unnecessarily once you have compiled your init file, thus slowing down your startup.

Comment: I do have `(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))`.

Comment: maybe it should be `(eval-when-compile (require 'cl-macs))`?

Comment: @npostavs: No, don't try to look at how CL is subdivided into files.  @event_jr: I guess you need `(require 'cl)` without the `eval-when-compile` because the `case` is hidden from the compiler by `defadvice`.

Comment: @Stefan is this a bug worth filing?